# Persistent Based Remember-Me for Regular Login in Spring Social Sample

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-social, remember-me

So I want to add a remember-me feature onto the Spring Social Showcase-Sec-XML sample. So I want to make it a persistent-based remember-me however whenever I add the datasource to the remember-me I get an error.

This is my code in the security.xml

```
<http use-expressions="true">
    <!-- Authentication policy -->
    <form-login login-page="/signin" login-processing-url="/signin/authenticate" authentication-failure-url="/signin?param.error=bad_credentials" />
    <logout logout-url="/signout" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/favicon.ico" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/auth/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/signin/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/signup/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/disconnect/facebook" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"  />
    <remember-me key="jbcpCalendar"
                data-source-ref="dataSource"/>

    <!--  Spring Social Security authentication filter -->
    <custom-filter ref="socialAuthenticationFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
</http>
```

This is the socialAuthenticationFilter bean that's giving the error.

```
<bean id="socialAuthenticationFilter" class="org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationFilter"
    c:_0-ref="authenticationManager"
    c:_1-ref="userIdSource"
    c:_2-ref="usersConnectionRepository"
    c:_3-ref="connectionFactoryLocator"
    p:signupUrl="/spring-social-showcase/signup"
    p:rememberMeServices-ref="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices#0" /> <!-- TODO: Figure out how to wire this without this name -->
```

This is the stack trace that comes out ):

```
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'socialAuthenticationFilter' while setting 
constructor argument with key [2]; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 

Error creating bean with name 'socialAuthenticationFilter' 
defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/social-security.xml]: Cannot 
resolve reference to bean 
'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices#0'
while setting bean property 'rememberMeServices'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No bean named   
'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices#0' is defined
```

Is there a way to make it use persistent based remember me when its a regular login?

Answer (score 1):

I think you must put an alias on the namespace configured remembermeservices :

```
<remember-me services-alias="toto"
             key="jbcpCalendar"
             data-source-ref="dataSource"/>
```

And the refer to it using the alias in your socialAuthenticationFilter configuration :

```
<bean id="socialAuthenticationFilter" class="org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationFilter"
    c:_0-ref="authenticationManager"
    c:_1-ref="userIdSource"
    c:_2-ref="usersConnectionRepository"
    c:_3-ref="connectionFactoryLocator"
    p:signupUrl="/spring-social-showcase/signup"
    p:rememberMeServices-ref="toto" />
```